# Indentation after try and except in multiple for loops python

Tags: python

I'm using try and except indentation. How should I indent after I the try and except code.

Example:

```
    try: 
        for elem in 

    browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'):
            elem.click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException: 
        for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'):
            elem.click()
    for ele in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'):
        ele.click()
```

I'm using "try and except" because I keep getting an error of StaleElementReferenceException. The only thing is that I need to use try and except multiple times in loops.

Comment: Can you annotate your code so we can see where you want it to catch the exception and where you want it to continue after?

Comment: This is basic Python syntax, not an issue for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @adamkgray did that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you did right, the next line after the except that is out of the except should be indented at the same level. So:

```
try:
    bla()
except X as y:
    foo()

bar()
```

Note the additional blank line before bar to keep the code more readable.

Also, in the try block you can move the call browser.find_elements_by_xpath to a variable assignment before, and that way keep your code a bit more readable.
e.g.

```
all_options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option')
for option in all_options:
    option.click()
```

In case you want to have another try except wrapping the other loop in the except, you can do that nicely in multiple ways. My recommendation is to wrap the loop in a function that will "convert" the exception to a return value:

```
def click_all_options(path):
    try:
        for option in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(path):
            option.click()
        return True
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return False
```

and in the code:

```
select1 = '/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'
select2 = '/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'
result = click_all_options(select1):
if not result:
    click_all_options(select2):
```

Comment: but what if the second for loop also requires a try and except?

Comment: I would suggest adding a function, let's call it click_all_options. I will add to my answer to clarify.

Comment: how would that help? Can I use the function outside the try and except part?

Comment: I'm sorry but one more doubt. Where did we use the second path?

Comment: A and B are the paths, you can use proper constants for them, or use the original inline strings. I omitted them for clarify of the code.

Comment: but the "path" that has been mentioned, is it for the first loop or the second loop?

Comment: It is for both. If you call click_all_options() twice with two different parameters, then the loop will run two times, each time with a different path value.

Comment: So, the code of def click_all_options should be written twice in my code?

Comment: also what is A and B?

Comment: You don't need to write the code of the function twice, that's the point of functions. Re A and B - they were just constants, I edited my answer to remove them.

Comment: the code worked. but the problem is that the second loop is nested within the first one but the for loop for the first one completes the entire round within the first list and the last element is selected for the second loop. Whereas my aim is for it to be sequential. Example: first element in first list, first element in second list, second element in second list and so on...